# sample code on android developer site crash

Tags: android, android-intent

So I just started development with android and implemented the sample code on the development site step by step.

the first few worked fine, but I'm stuck on intents.

I've gone through the code and its the exact replica of the one on the developer site. then why is it crashing when the activity changes at startActivity(intent) ?

help !

This is the first activity:::

```
package com.example.Trial;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class TrialActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myapp.MESSAGE";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
    public void sendMessage(View view) { 
        // Do something in response to button 
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisaplyMessageActivity.class); 
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message); 
        String message = editText.getText().toString(); 
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

This is the activity it calls:

```
package com.example.Trial;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DisaplyMessageActivity extends Activity { 
    @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = getIntent(); 
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(TrialActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
TextView textView = new TextView(this); 
textView.setTextSize(40);
textView.setText(message); 
setContentView(textView);
} }
```

This is main.xml::

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message" />

        <Button
        android:onClick="sendMessage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_send" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and this is string.xml:::

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">My First App</string>
    <string name="edit_message">Enter a message</string>
    <string name="button_send">Send</string>
</resources>
```

the FATAL EXCEPTION trails to::

06-18 21:30:51.377: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at com.example.Trial.TrialActivity.sendMessage(TrialActivity.java:23)

thanks a lot

Comment: can you post the full stack trace and the exact exception?

Comment: Try cleaning the project (Project > Clean in Eclipse or `ant clean` from the command line), then try your app again.

Comment: @user1349663 : Do you realise you spelled 'Display' wrong for your second Activity?... `DisaplyMessageActivity`. You've done it consistently in your `TrialActivity` which is fine but if it's registered in the manifest as `DisplayMessageActivity` then that could be the problem.

Comment: ya I did realised that a long time age. But since I spelt it wrong in one place, instead of finding it everywhere, I just decided to make the same error consistently.

Answer (score 0):

Did you include `DisplayMessageActivity` in your manifest?  You should have one for your main activity and one entry for every other activity as well:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".TrialActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity" >
    </activity>
```

Comment: ya i did include it in the manifest... forgot to include the manifest here but thats another thing